# 'dict' object has no attribute 'value' but I see it in the dictionary when I print it out

Tags: python, dictionary, data-science

When I run this line of code: `print(response.keys());`

I get this response:  `dict_keys(['@odata.context', 'value'])`

When I run this line of code: `print(response.value);`

I get this response: `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'value'`

When I print out the entire dictionary I see the attribute value.  Below is what part of it printed out.  I can clearly see value as an attribute.

```
{'@odata.context': '$metadata#Property(ListPrice,YearBuilt,ListingKey)', 'value': [{'ListPrice': 895000.0, 'YearBuilt': 0, 'ListingKey': '1000006'}, {'ListPrice': 84800.0, 'YearBuilt': 0, 'ListingKey': '1000096'}
```

Any ideas what is happening?

Comment: In Python you access a dictionary’s keys with square brackets: `response['value']`.

Comment: You can't access dict elements as `response.value`.  You need to use `response['value']`, or `response.get('value')`.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to access the dict elements as an attribute `response.value`.

In Python to access a dictionary’s keys is by using square brackets, in your case it will be:

```
response['value']
```

Answer (score 2):

The dictionary's member function is called `.values()` and not `.value`. You missed the `s` and the brackets.

Try:

```
 print(resonse.values())
```

Or try to access the element:

```
 print(response['value'])
```

Where `value` happens to be a dictionary key. Obviously, this might be confusing.